# How do I call GestureRecognizer method programatically on Swift 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm doing those Stanford course, and on that part about gestures I couldn't replicated the pinchGesture, it simply doesn't works and even don't call the breakpoint inside the method that are supposed to be called.
I'm copying my code below

inside FaceViewController

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
        didSet {
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))))
            updateUI()
        }
    }
```

inside FaceView

```swift
@objc
    func changeScale(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .changed, .ended:
            scale *= recognizer.scale
            recognizer.scale = 1.0
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

I'm on Xcode 9 and swift is version 4.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you push your code on GitHub

Comment: I did not see at the beginning that the function you are calling was living inside the `FaceView` class. 

Your code works for me. Are you sure your `faceView` is connected to your `@IBOulet`??

To connect it you need to right-click on your view and drag it to your IBOutlet definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see at the beginning that the function you are calling was living inside the `FaceView` class.

Your code works for me. Are you sure your `faceView` is connected to your `@IBOulet`??

Should look like this:

[image]

To connect it you need to right-click on your view and drag it to your IBOutlet definition

Answer (score 1):

set, faceView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
And it' ll work.